# Can't control the NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I need to fire fetch request controller after finish the updating. Is their any method to control this.

Reason is some parent entity have child entity called "Image". This use for store the image. This images are download separately.

Because of this reason i can't get images when fetch request controller fire(image download not finished).

Answer (score 0):

Ask the fetchedResultsController to refetch by calling performFetch.

```
NSError *error;
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
```